ATmega328 experiences freezing or hangs when the ceiling fan is turned on or off

I've been working on a project, but I've hit a snag. Every time I try to turn the ceiling fan on or off, ATmega328 gets hung/freezes. Let me break down the project for you, so you know what's going on and why I'm having trouble.
Project Setup:
So, I've got a main PCB (designed by myself) with an ATmega328 and some relays to control stuff turning on and off. Then, there are two other PCBs connected to the main PCB one using a protocol called I2C. These two PCBs have stuff like an OLED screen, MCP23017, and a touch sensor (TTP226). They send touch info to the main board, which updates the screen accordingly.
The Problem:
Everything works great until I mess with the ceiling fan or any other heavy-duty stuff that switches on and off. Whenever that happens, the ATmega328 on the main board just freezes. I've tried hooking up the main board to a 12V battery instead of the usual power supply, but no luck. I really want to get this project running smoothly with the power supply, but I'm stuck.
If you've got any ideas or tips on how to fix this, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks for lending a hand!

You did not post the whole schematics. Where is the Atmega328P? How long wires you have between boards? Are the wires or cable shielded? What does the wiring looks like? Is there any shieding or case? Have you debugged where in the code it freezes to find out why it freezes? The device is clearly sensitive to electromagnetic interference from a possible spark or current surge when the fan is switched.

I've utilized two meters of twisted and shielded wiring between the boards. While I believe the freezing problem isn't caused by the code itself, I suspect it may be due to interference from the ceiling fan's operation. However, I'm uncertain about how to address this issue.

AVR have always been notorious for their crappy EMC performance, which is one of many reasons why Arduinos and the like aren't used in industrial/automotive applications. That being said, you might be able to salvage it if you can find out the exact cause: is it low-voltage detect or latch-up, is it some other MCU reset etc.

Anyway, without MCU schematic and/or the PCB layout, we can't help you.

@Lundin i attached schematic please check

@mechaTronicsTech In addition to other details, please tell how the twisted pair wiring connects to the I2C connector? It makes a difference, as there are both good and bad ways of doing it.

@Justme I've utilized two meters of twisted and shielded wiring between the boards. While I believe the freezing problem isn't caused by the code itself, I suspect it may be due to interference from the ceiling fan's operation. However, I'm uncertain about how to address this issue.

At a glance I see no obvious problems, other than that the optocouplers are dead silicon dummies only serving the purpose of making the BoM more expensive. The simpler switcher regulators are also prone to cause noise and the layout there will be critical. Most likely culprits are however the board layout or grounding. What I'm not following though is if this product is supposed to be activating the mentioned ceiling fan or if it just some generic ceiling fan not part of the product, powered from mains, causing the board to hiccup?

@Lundin it just a generic ceiling fan no part of the product, powered from the mains and causing the board--------this is true

That is very very bad then... you have some serious layout and/or wiring problems, I would guess.

@Lundin Your support is greatly appreciated as I've been grappling with this situation for the past five months. Please let me know what additional information you require, and I will promptly provide it.

@mechaTronicsTech Let me ask again, in which way you have connected the twisted pair wiring between boards?  How are they paired? Are SCL and SDA in same pair? Is both wires of a pair the same signal so you effectively just have 4 wires without pairing? Is the cable shield connected in any way to somewhere or floating? Do you realize you have arcing and sparking mains switching relays right next to the AVR, sending electromagnetic interference to it? The PCB layout is critical to stable operation and mains safety. Also, don't press the reset button, you might blow something up.

@mechaTronicsTech If you post the PCB layout and stack-up I'm sure there's plenty of folks that can give feedback on it. The regulator and relay parts in particular.

@Ludin i posted PCB layout please check

Some I2C receiver code can hang endless if the interface receives an EMI impact. So for debugging I would set a diagnostic output before calling the I2C receiver and clear it afterwards. Check this output when the MCU "freezes". If this output is active, I may have some ideas how to proceed.

Not related to the question, but the distance between mains connector pins and tracks L and N and between N and the ground plane is critical low. There is room enough to improve that.

Disconnect the fan then switch the relay for the fan.  The idea is to see if it is the fan or the relay causing the glitches.

You have too many variables. Complexity exponentiates, which wins. Suggestions: #1: Get a power module to (at least temporarily) replace the simple switcher. If not, move simple switcher to its own board. Also try as directly as possible copying the layout suggestion from the datasheet. #2. Move Arduino to its own board, and make the connections to just one relay (ceiling fan), and make it long enough so you can experiment with the relative position of the two to see where interference starts/stops etc. #3. Working with line voltages can take life (even yours). So... Hire a pro to verify!
